# How to get any output from “git diff-tree --stdin”?

Tags: git, git-diff, git-diff-tree

The man-page of `git diff-tree` suggests that I can do a combined diff (`--cc`) with a bunch of tree-objects of my choosing. You have to use the `--stdin` option for this. But I can’t get `--stdin` to output anything at all.

Example:

```
$ git diff-tree --stdin
a b
a b
$
```

Here I typed <kbd>a</kbd><kbd><Space></kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd><Enter></kbd><kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>: It doesn’t even complain that `a` and `b` is bad input... But even with valid commit hashes and/or further options I never get any output at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must provide **full** hashes of commit or tree objects to `git diff-tree --stdin`:

```
  $ git log -3 --pretty=%H
  a30ec5de57bbfa0c19045f3c094ec6eb4d808eb4
  f0939d956ad9ef2a00360139a6f1d1ad66accbe5
  fcdb73de293b2442231e5d8ce19f9c7d1640d186

  $ # lines typed on stdin are marked by ->
  $ git diff-tree --stdin
->fcdb73de293b2442231e5d8ce19f9c7d1640d186 a30ec5de57bbfa0c19045f3c094ec6eb4d808eb4
  fcdb73de293b2442231e5d8ce19f9c7d1640d186
  :040000 040000 e2aed2af18fb5293903a0d0b78c23e00a893394d c56666f973b77d92d52b68a14c5a26ac3508571a M    example
  :040000 000000 7cc3373fd5cad3bfe6ec261e9dcc3a9e97efe488 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 D    prc
  :000000 040000 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 275872c00a9f51016d2273419345b3b1d7535630 A    src
->275872c00a9f51016d2273419345b3b1d7535630 7cc3373fd5cad3bfe6ec261e9dcc3a9e97efe488
  275872c00a9f51016d2273419345b3b1d7535630 7cc3373fd5cad3bfe6ec261e9dcc3a9e97efe488
  :100644 100644 f26b2198fd9a0103f57a5bd828e58043507ea7b7 c52116f6d185548061058099dfe4c9e50d523aff M    chord.cpp
  :100644 100644 fcbfcdc036fb53733176ed30fd82eb261a990d5b 403e323f332a18b45dfdebfd3a8bfb1a62158bb4 M    chord.hpp
  :100644 100644 11a931f795b44cd916e1607d819eed4d5342edba 333b596faf596d73758bce949e6d86e596153126 M    polyphonic_track.cpp
  :100644 100644 7196835de2385d3f1e0b20073d327cb432ed436c f9fbbac93ef6fc19ae99113ff39a06f4df50720e M    polyphonic_track.hpp
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way:

```
git rev-list HEAD | git diff-tree --stdin
```

But, before Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), "`git diff-tree --pretty --notes`" used to hit an assertion failure, as it forgot to initialize the notes subsystem.

See [commit 5778b22](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5778b22b3d690495e724276663c36ccd5329da4d) (21 Apr 2020) by [Taylor Blau (`ttaylorr`)](https://github.com/ttaylorr).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5a96715](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a96715eb7451e81b3d981f2b4797a1aa4f1afdd), 28 Apr 2020)</sup>

> ### [`diff-tree.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5778b22b3d690495e724276663c36ccd5329da4d): load notes machinery when required
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Jeff King</sup>
>   <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>
>   <sup>Acked-by: Jeff King</sup>
>
> Since its introduction in [7249e91](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7249e91287443c02b2c7eed272a579dae44984ad) ("`[`revision.c`](https`://github.com/git/git/blob/5778b22b3d690495e724276663c36ccd5329da4d/revision.c): support --notes command-line option", 2011-03-29, Git v1.7.6-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/23f536cf6236bf2a29026fea52c6bf7624b6485d) listed in [batch #0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/)), combining '`--notes`' with any option that causes us to format notes (e.g., '`--pretty`', '`--format="%N"`', etc) results in a failed assertion at runtime.
>
> ```
> $ git rev-list HEAD | git diff-tree --stdin --pretty=medium --notes
> commit 8f3d9f354286745c751374f5f1fcafee6b3f3136
> git: notes.c:1308: format_display_notes: Assertion `display_notes_trees' failed.
> Aborted
> ```
>
> This failure is due to diff-tree not calling '`load_display_notes`' to initialize the notes machinery.
>
> Ordinarily, this failure isn't triggered, because it requires passing both '`--notes`' and another of the above mentioned options.
>   In the case of '`--pretty`', for example, we set '`opt->verbose_header`', causing '`show_log()`' to eventually call '`format_display_notes()`', which expects a non-NULL '`display_note_trees`'.
>
> Without initializing the notes machinery, '`display_note_trees`' remains `NULL`, and thus triggers an assertion failure.
>
> Fix this by initializing the notes machinery after parsing our options.